# Алгоритм "Горячие предложения"?

Tags: php

Добрый день! Помогите реализовать алгоритм "Горячие предложения".

Вкратце: Есть таблица с продуктами, со стандартными полями цена, наименование ну и т д. Так же есть поле hot которое принимает 0 или 1 . Если 0 то не горяшие предложения, если 1 то горящие. Когда я ставлю 1 продукт показываться в горящим, но только на последнем месте, а надо на первом месте.

**Вот собствено проблема:**

**1) Последнее горящие предложение не показывается на первой позиции а на последней.**

**2) Нужно доработать алгоритм, а может и придумать другой**

Подскажите люди добрые, в каком направлении тут двигаться?

Comment: при чем тут "алгоритм"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ищите запрос к бд который выгребает горячие предложения, и добавьте(или измените) метод сортировки order by

Comment: ок. Но есть вариант того что товар был добавлен давно, а сейчас хотят сделать его горящим. Тогда по какому полю сортировать?

Comment: добавить поле addHot в таблицу товаров и обновлять его при добавлении товаров в горячие предложения. В запросе update `product` set `hot` = '1', `addHot` = 'время добавления'. В запросе выборки ГП будет order by `addHot` desc.

Comment: Понятно, будем реализовывать, спасибо! Лайк!